# how to upload multiple imges through a constant uploadpath

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using the code below to upload multiple images, but is showing error when I am uploading more than one image through different form fields. My code is:

```
$image = 'image'.$i.$j;
      $image_store = $_FILES[$image]['name'];
define('uploadpath','../images/');
      $target = uploadpath. $image_store ;
```

and the error is

```
CONSTANT uploadpath Already defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says, you're defining `uploadpath` multiple times, because of this line:

```
define('uploadpath','../images/');
```

It must be in a loop somewhere. Remove it from there (you only need to define it once, so put it out of the loop), or put a check:

```
if(!defined('uploadpath')) define('uploadpath','../images/');
```